# Knockout JS Cascading State / City Dropdown (with JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, knockout.js

I have two fields, state and city. When the user selects their state I'm sending a call to the server which is returning:

```
[{"id":"4488","rc_abbr":"BILLINGS"},{"id":"4489","rc_abbr":"MISSOULA"},{"id":"4490","rc_abbr":"GREATFALLS"},{"id":"4491","rc_abbr":"HELENA"},{"id":"4492","rc_abbr":"BOZEMAN"},{"id":"4493","rc_abbr":"BUTTE"},{"id":"4494","rc_abbr":"HAMILTON"},{"id":"4495","rc_abbr":"BELGRADE"},{"id":"4496","rc_abbr":"LIVINGSTON"},{"id":"4497","rc_abbr":"LAUREL"},{"id":"4498","rc_abbr":"MILES CITY"},{"id":"4499","rc_abbr":"STEVENSVL"},{"id":"4500","rc_abbr":"LEWISTOWN"},{"id":"4501","rc_abbr":"ANACONDA"},{"id":"4502","rc_abbr":"DILLON"},{"id":"4503","rc_abbr":"HARDIN"},{"id":"4504","rc_abbr":"GLENDIVE"},{"id":"4505","rc_abbr":"DEER LODGE"},{"id":"4506","rc_abbr":"SIDNEY"},{"id":"4507","rc_abbr":"CUT BANK"},{"id":"4508","rc_abbr":"MANHATTAN"},{"id":"4509","rc_abbr":"RED LODGE"},{"id":"4510","rc_abbr":"FRENCHTOWN"},{"id":"4511","rc_abbr":"THREEFORKS"},{"id":"4512","rc_abbr":"COLUMBUS"},{"id":"4513","rc_abbr":"CONRAD"},{"id":"4514","rc_abbr":"SHELBY"},{"id":"4515","rc_abbr":"COLSTRIP"},{"id":"4516","rc_abbr":"WYELLOWSTN"},{"id":"4517","rc_abbr":"FORSYTH"},{"id":"4518","rc_abbr":"GALATNGTWY"},{"id":"4519","rc_abbr":"JOLIET"},{"id":"4520","rc_abbr":"GARDINER"},{"id":"4521","rc_abbr":"CLYDE PARK"},{"id":"4522","rc_abbr":"FROMBERG"},{"id":"4523","rc_abbr":"FAIRVIEW"},{"id":"4524","rc_abbr":"BRIDGER"},{"id":"4525","rc_abbr":"WIBAUX"},{"id":"4526","rc_abbr":"TERRY"},{"id":"4527","rc_abbr":"WILSALL"},{"id":"4528","rc_abbr":"WOLF CREEK"},{"id":"4529","rc_abbr":"COOKE CITY"},{"id":"4530","rc_abbr":"SILVERTIP"},{"id":"4531","rc_abbr":"NO PARKMAN"}]
```

In knockout I need to update the city field with this data. My problem is something to do with the way I'm getting the ajax data success response and putting it in, I'm not sure on the proper syntax.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VJbVs/

HTML

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedState">
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
<option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
<option value="DE">Delaware</option>
<option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
<option value="GA">Georgia</option>
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
<option value="IL">Illinois</option>
<option value="IN">Indiana</option>
<option value="IA">Iowa</option>
<option value="KS">Kansas</option>
<option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
<option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
<option value="ME">Maine</option>
<option value="MD">Maryland</option>
<option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
<option value="MI">Michigan</option>
<option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
<option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
<option value="MO">Missouri</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
<option value="NV">Nevada</option>
<option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
<option value="NY">New York</option>
<option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
<option value="OH">Ohio</option>
<option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
<option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
<option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
<option value="TX">Texas</option>
<option value="UT">Utah</option>
<option value="VT">Vermont</option>
<option value="VA">Virginia</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>
<option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<select data-bind="options: cities, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'ID', value: selectedCity"></select>
```

Script

```
(function () {

    var ViewModel = function () {

        this.selectedState = ko.observable();
        this.selectedState.states = [];

        this.selectedCity = ko.observable();

        this.selectedState.subscribe(function () {
            this.selectedCity(undefined);
        }, this);

        var getById = function (items, id) {
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(items, function (item) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'activate/get/coverage',
                    type: 'POST',
                    beforeSend: function(){},
                    data: ko.toJSON({state: item.ID}),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    complete: function(data){}, 
                    success: function (result) {this.selectedState.states = result;}
                });
                return item.ID == id;
            });
        };

        this.cities = ko.computed(function () {
            var state = getById(this.selectedState.states, this.selectedState());
            return state ? ko.utils.arrayMap(state.States, function (item) {
                return {
                    id: item.ID,
                    rc_abbr: item.Name
                };
            }) : [];
        }, this);

    };

    var model = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById('didScreen'));

})();
```

Comment: [Deleted earlier comment, was unclear] Your code is very confusing. You try to access `selectedState.states` in the `cities` computed while it is still an empty array (during construction), and call `arrayFirst` on it, so that `getById` returns null. Even if it didn't though, its comparing those items by `ID` to the selected state, which will be a letter combo. Then you try to access the `States` property of an object that won't have that property until after an ajax call completes (which sets `states`, when it looks like it will be a collection of cities), meaning that will be undefined.

Comment: Do you have any code suggestions though? I understand what your saying is wrong but my brain is melting over this, I'm not sure what to do to make it work.

Comment: Take a look at this, and let me know if you have any questions: http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/6xmD8/1/

Comment: I remade the script and got the state / city drop downs working with each other with simple jquery code, but the way I need it to work is on a foreach, and that code doesn't know to use the next line. Here is the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/aKbHE/1/

Comment: You should join me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27045/room-for-tyrsius-and-stephen-harman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer, we spent a lot of time in [chat talking](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27045/room-for-tyrsius-and-stephen-harman) (don't know if others can open that link).

The HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <select data-bind="options: $parent.states, optionsText: 'name', value: state"></select>
    <select data-bind="options: cities, optionsText: 'name', value: city"></select>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: newItem">Add Item</button>
```

The JS:

```
var Item = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.state = ko.observable();
    self.city = ko.observable();
    self.cities = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.state.subscribe(function(state) {
        self.city("");
        self.cities.removeAll();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                json: ko.toJSON([
                    { id: 1, name: "Billings"},
                    { id: 2, name: "Sweego"},
                    { id: 3, name: "NorthFall"}
                ]),
                delay: 2
            },
            success: function(response) {
                self.cities(response);
            }
        });
    });
};

var ViewModel = function(states) {
    var self = this;
    self.states = states;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([new Item()]);
    self.newItem = function() {
        self.items.push(new Item());
    };
    self.remove = function(item) {
        self.items.remove(item);
    };
};
```

Here is the [final fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/qCEvH/2/)

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you for all your time and dedication in the chat room.